# Border around active image in a gallery using css and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am rendering thumbnail images from a directory as horizontal gallery using PHP.  I am trying to put a border around the clicked image by setting the image to `active`, which is not working.  The following is the html and css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<style>
  #loaded_img_panel {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }

  #loaded_img_panel > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
  }

  #loaded_img_panel ul li img {
    display: inline;
    width: 210px;
    height:175px;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #loaded_img_panel img:active {
      border: 0.4em solid red;
  }


  #loaded_img_panel img:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
      border: 0.4em solid red;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="loaded_img_panel" id="loaded_img_panel">    
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('load',function(e) {
  var folder = "thumbnails";
  if (folder !== null && folder !== "") {
    $.post("loadimages.php", {'folder' : folder}, function(output){
      $("#loaded_img_panel").html(output).show();
      });
    }   
  });

  //Put border around the selected image
  $('#loaded_img_panel').on('click', 'img', function() {
    $('#loaded_img_panel img').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
</script>
```

The following is the php script:

**loadimages.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$folder = $_POST['folder'];
$tardir = "projects/" . $folder . "/thumb/*.jpg" ;
$files = glob($tardir);
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    $filname = basename($num, ".jpg");
    $filnam = substr($filname, -5);
    $filnam = rtrim($filnam);
    echo '<ul class="item">';
    echo '<li><img src="'.$num.'" id="thumbNails'.$filnam.'"/>';
    echo '<figcaption class="caption" name="caption">' . $filnam . '</figcaption>';
    echo '</li></ul>';
}

?>
```

The php renders images from the directory and the css sets it to horizontal gallery.  On hover and onclick I am able to see the red border, but when I release the mouse the box disappears.

I tried, changing the click path from img to `#loaded_img_panel > ul > li > img` and similar other variations but they were not working.

Comment: You need to change `#loaded_img_panel img:active` to `#loaded_img_panel img.active`

Comment: @Nick Thank you...sometimes I wonder how I take the ctrl+c and ctrl+v for granted.  I can accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `#loaded_img_panel img:active` to `#loaded_img_panel img.active`. That way once you assign the `active` class to the image it will remain highlighted instead of just while you click on it (which is what `:active`) means.